# grouping and summating array of data by element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a new array grouping payments by month regardless of the account type given by 3 categories (DEA,ISA,SIPP)

My data is of the form

```
var arr = [
        { 'DEA','1', 'Jan',1266 },
        { 'ISA','1', 'Jan',621 },
        { 'SIPP','1', 'Jan',552 },
        { 'DEA','2', 'Feb',889 },
        { 'ISA','2', 'Feb',921 },
        { 'SIPP','2', 'Feb',901 },
      ];
```

Month No 1 or 2 etc is redundant data, ie. not required in my output

I need to group the payments by month in the following form into a new array:

```
var newarr =
[
{ 'Jan',2439 },
{ 'Feb',2711 },
];
```

I have used the following code as my starting point which groups by age category and summates the TOTAL, but I have been unable to apply to my data successfully yet

```js
var arr = [
            { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 6},
            { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 3},
            { AGENDADOR: 'AGE203', TOTAL : 5},
            { AGENDADOR: 'AGE028', TOTAL : 9},
        ];
      
var totals = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
  (r[o.AGENDADOR])? r[o.AGENDADOR] += o.TOTAL : r[o.AGENDADOR] = o.TOTAL;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(totals);
```

Any help much appreciated to get me started, thanks.

Many Thanks

Colin

Comment: And, what have you tried to solve that? btw, that's an invalid input.

Comment: Your data is invalid syntax.

Comment: I am new to javascript, I have tried to use the reduce function as shown in another question successfully replicating for a similar array, but I have not been able to apply it to my data due to its multi dimension nature, i will keep trying thanks Colin

Comment: Post those attempts with reduce.

Comment: var arr = [
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 6},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE270', TOTAL : 3},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE203', TOTAL : 5},
        { AGENDADOR: 'AGE028', TOTAL : 9},
    ],
  This was my starting point albeit using different data
  totals = arr.reduce(function (r, o) {
    (r[o.AGENDADOR])? r[o.AGENDADOR] += o.TOTAL : r[o.AGENDADOR] = o.TOTAL;
    return r;
  }, {});

Comment: You should rewrite your question and post the code of the last comment.

Comment: str, is the data invalid because there are no qualifiers, sorry if novice question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sum up the months, an alternative is maintaining an array of months which is used to loop and extract the values you need to sum.

Basically, the function `reduce` groups the values by month and the function `Object.values` extracts the grouped values as an array.

*This approach will extract as many months are presented in the objects.*

```js
let months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'];// and so on.
let arr = [        { 'DEA':'1', 'Jan':1266 },        { 'ISA':'1', 'Jan':621 },        { 'SIPP':'1', 'Jan':552 },        { 'DEA':'2', 'Feb':889 },        { 'ISA':'2', 'Feb':921 },        { 'SIPP':'2', 'Feb':901 }      ];
      
let result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  months.forEach(m => {
    if (m in c) (a[m] || (a[m] = {[m]: 0}))[m] += c[m];
  });
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; }
```